# Submit forms from both parent and iframe to same target

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

Parent form

```
<form action="target.php" method="post" id="form1">
```

Iframe form

```
<form action="target.php" method="post" id="form2">
```

This JS works fine submitting from Iframe using a button placed in parent

```
var iframedoc = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document;
var inputs = iframedoc.getElementsByTagName('input');
iframedoc.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
```

I try to modify JS with **document.getElementById("form1").submit();** to send parent form as well but I end up with results only from one form and not both

Comment: Most likely because submitting the parent page causes the iframe to be unloaded too, stopping an requests queued or in progress. That's why this sounds like a less than ideal approach to whatever it is you're trying to do. I'd suggest you retrieve the details of the iframe form and append them to the form in the main window and submit that form only.

Comment: appending sounds great, I didn't know there is a way to get from iframe form and send only one form with all inputs

Comment: Is the content of the iframe and the parent window on the same domain?

Comment: yes they are on the same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="
var iframedoc = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document;
var inputs = iframedoc.getElementsByTagName('input');
$('#form1').append($(inputs));
document.getElementById('form1').submit();">
```